# removeEventListener on document in functional component react is not working

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

i am adding and removing eventListeners using following code

```
 if (isScanning) {
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', BoxkeypressHandler, true);
      } else {
        document.addEventListener('keypress', BoxkeypressHandler, true);
      }

associated method 

const BoxkeypressHandler = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
    const process = () => {
      timeout = setTimeout(async() => {

        const scanObj = { barcodeValue };
        const fnsku = barcodeValue.match('^[A-Z0-9]{10}$');

        if (fnsku) {
          extend(scanObj, { scanBy: 'fnsku' });
        }
        if (scanObj.scanBy) {
          const itemExist = shipmentList.find(item => item.fulfillmentNetworkSku == scanObj.barcodeValue)
          if(itemExist){
            setScanData(scanObj);
            if(scanType == 'batch'){
              setModel(true);
              document.removeEventListener('keypress', BoxkeypressHandler);
            }
            else{
              if(selectedBox){
                await dispatch(AddScanItemToBox({
                  boxId: selectedBox,
                  item: {
                    fnSku: scanObj.barcodeValue,
                    quantity: 1
                  }
                }));
                success.play();
                await dispatch(GetBoxes());
                await dispatch(GetShipmentItems());
              }

            }
          }
          else{
            if(selectedBox){
              await dispatch(setFullfilmentField({
                field: 'message',
                value: "item no longer exist in shipments"
              }))
              await dispatch(setFullfilmentField({
                field: 'error',
                value: true
              }))
              sound.play();
            }
          }
        }
      }, 100);
    };
    if (charTime) charDiff = moment().diff(moment(charTime), 'miliseconds');
    charTime = new Date();

    const fetching = false;
    if (!fetching) {
      const char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
      if (e.which === 13) {
        process();
      } else if (charDiff < 50) {
        barcodeValue = barcodeValue.concat(char);
        process();
      } else {
        barcodeValue = char;
      }
    } else {
      barcodeValue = '';
    }

  };
```

event gets add and work perfectly fine and i can see the event listener using developer tool of chrome when i try to remove the eventListener  using above code it won't remove the event listener and still i can see the eventListener in developer tool chrome i tried multiple times removing the listener but no luck.

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: If that `removeEventListener` code isn't working, it's because you've created a **different** `BoxkeypressHandler` function from the one you added (probably this is in a place where the function gets created each time). You have to remove the **same function** you added, an equivalent one isn't sufficient.

Comment: i have edited the question please have a look

Comment: i am using the same method in adding and removing event listener from the document

Comment: Clearly they **aren't** the same function. Because if they were the same function, it would work. `removeEventListener` isn't broken. What is the context of `const BoxkeypressHandler = (e) => {`? Put a breakpoint on that line. How many times does it get triggered? If it's more than once, you're recreating the function, which results in a **different** function.

Comment: function is getting executed once if i add and remove event listener instantly or i remove inside the event listener function it works perfectly fine. but when i click manually to add and then click to remove it doesn't work